# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes before login screen, no dual boot

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, 20.04, asus

I have been trying to make Ubuntu 20.04 run on my new ASUS TUF for last 3 days without any luck.

Right now, the issue I am facing is that my system hangs on login screen.

I have already installed Nvidia drivers and loaded them.

Adding nomodeset doesn't work for me, the system gets stuck even before login screen.

I have already added intel_idle.max_cstate=1 in the grub, it worked for few reboots but then it stopped working.

Sometimes, like 1 out of 5 times, removing quiet works for me but not always. Also, it makes my system very slow.

The output for "lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display" is shown below:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I have also done the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

It helped for few reboots, while making the system slower, like opening and closing terminal took couple of minutes, but has stopped working now.

Can someone please help me with a permanent solution?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Have already done that, didn't work for me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the image of the output.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Output has been added.

Comment: The output looks good.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and faced same problem. The system were hanging in boot screen with connected HDMI cable. Although it was running well without the connected HDMI cable.

I am using following hardware:

- ASRock B460 board with LGA-1200
- Intel Core 10th gen. with UHD 630 integrated graphic.

My solution consists of following steps:

1. `sudo apt-get update | sudo apt-get upgrade -y`
2. Restart the system (disconnect HDMI before Ubuntu starts)
3. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
4. Set: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` just leave it empty
5. `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
6. Restart the system

The system does not have now this nice Ubuntu boot screen but instead prints everything on console, then login screen appears.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the booting issue when I was trying to boot with HDMI connected.
The presented solutions didn't work for me. So I ended up with downgrading of NVIDIA driver and it helped. I have issues with `nvidia-driver-460`, so I downgraded to `nvidia-driver-450`
The steps:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get udpate
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-450
sudo reboot
```

Btw I left grub config line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` empty.

Comment: This helped me, though my notebook still doesn't comes out of suspend

Comment: this helped me too

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I was able to find the answer.

Make sure you have already tried everything mentioned in the question first.

First, while you are starting your system enter the grub window.
Edit the grub window line which contains **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** by replacing everything after "**ro**" with "** quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1 $vt_handoff**".

This will make your system run.

If it doesn't, don't follow further steps and comment about the problem you faced.

Login and then open the terminal.

In terminal type,

**sudo gedit /etc/default/grub**

This will open your grub in text format, edit it by replacing anything after, **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=** with **"quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"**, save the file and in terminal run the following line, 
**sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg**.
Now reboot your system.

If after doing this everything works then it's well and good.
In my case I was not able to get audio to work after this step. If you face the same issue add **snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0** to the same line in grub, making it

**"quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1 snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"**

then run the following command

**sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg**

and reboot your system.

All should be fine after that.